# Responsive Menu Dropdown is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the dropdown menu is not showing please help me..

Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vryfgmh5/

and here is my sample code

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
<a href="#" class="header__icon" id="header__icon"></a>
<a href="#" class="header__logo">Logo</a>     
<nav class="menu">
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">About</a>
<a href="#">Blog</a>
<a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>  
</header>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

(function($) {

$('#header__icon').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('body').toggleClass('with--sidebar');
});

$('#site-cache').click(function(e) {
$('body').removeClass('with--sidebar');
});

})(jQuery);

});
```

Comment: You've forgotten to add jQuery. Here's a working example with jQuery loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/vryfgmh5/2/. Your code is fine by the way - seems to work perfectly.

Comment: i've added <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>  on the html but still doesn't work

Comment: Then wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){})`, perhaps the script is trying to run BEFORE jQuery has been loaded.

Comment: can u update the jsfiddle? i dunno how.. please

Comment: it's working now thanks

Comment: OK, that's good - happy to help

Answer (score 2):

If you right-click on your browser and select "inspect" you'll see an error in the browser console 
**"(index):160 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"**

In the fiddle page, you don't have jquery included.  I'm assuming this might be the problem with your local code too.